# Method or application for updating files and/or applications on many remote computers?

Tags: windows, file-management, remote-access, diagnostics

I have several Windows 10 and Windows 7 machines that are operating remotely. Sometimes, certain files or executables need to be updated. This would involve the following.

1. Close running program.
2. Delete its current executable
3. Copy the new executable
4. Replace (delete and copy) any files as needed
5. Relaunch the program

I was wondering if there is an application of some sort that would allow me to control this across individual systems (individual update) or across all systems (bulk update).

It would be nice if there would be a nice GUI and centralization to this with logging etc.

Note, I didn't find a tag for "Update". Pointers of where to post would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can go as big or small as you like with this. Microsoft SCCM for example is probably overkill though.

You could do it via a PowerShell script that remotely connects to each computer and runs those tasks. Something like this:

```
$computers = "computer1", "computer2"
foreach ($computer in $computers){
get-process winword -computername $computer | stop-process
remove-item \\$computername\c$\apps\winword.exe
copy-item \\server\software\winword.exe \\$computername\c$\apps -force
}
```

You could also check the version number of the exe like this:

```
(get-ChildItem c:\apps\winword.exe).VersionInfo
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [GRR Rapid Response](https://grr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what-is-grr.html) "GRR Rapid Response is an incident response framework focused on remote live forensics."

However, *while it *is* a remote forensics framework,* it can be also used to do what you are asking for as available actions include stopping running processes, requesting the download and installation of files & starting processes running.

Actions such as the above can be triggered on individual machines, groups of machines, etc. or in response to specific events.

A client needs to be installed to each of the machines to be controlled and a server is used to provide the control & diagnostics. The server is controlled via a web interface (rather than a desktop GUI).

Plentiful logs can be maintained - *it is after all primarily a diagnostic/forensics tool!*.

Client software can be installed on Windows 7 & 10 *(well tested on 64 bit but build of 32 bit should be possible)*, OS-X & Linux.
Server software 64bit Ubuntu 18.04 but also supports [docker](https://grr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-grr-server/via-docker.html) and cloud deployments.
User Interface - via web browser giving GUI control plus various APIs.

It is Open Source so you will not have to pay any cash for it but may have to invest some time in learning how to use it.